# Can't contain video using flexgrid Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am having difficulty containing a video element inside my flexgrid. I am simply trying to organize my page to have the navbar at the top of the screen, with a background video playing below it, filling the rest of the screen. Currently I am able to center my navbar over the video, but the video is causing scrolldown functionality. When I replace the video with a simple text object, everything appears to work fine.

```
// Navbar is a component
<div className='flex flex-col min-h-screen min-w-full'>
  <div><Navbar/></div>
  <div className='flex-1'> // Should expand the remainder of the screen height
    <video src="videos/Demo-Video.mp4"
    autoPlay  
    loop
    muted
    className='object-cover' // Is supposed to shrink or expand the video the length of the parent div
  >Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but removing the div wrapping the video might help, or scaling the video to fit that div.

```
// Navbar is a component
<div className='flex flex-col min-h-screen min-w-full'>
  <div><Navbar/></div>
  //<div className=''> // Should expand the remainder of the screen height
    <video src="videos/Demo-Video.mp4"
    autoPlay  
    loop
    muted
    className='flex-1 object-cover' // Is supposed to shrink or expand the video the length of the parent div
  >Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
  //</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I will give this a shot when I get off work. What is the reason why you believe removing the div may be beneficial? Thanks!